# Removing rows in a data frame based on multiple criteria in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I hope that I have formatted my question correctly as this is my first time posting and fairly new to R.

Below is a small sample of some athlete movement data that I am currently using.

````html
```
      Player   Period      Dist    Date          Type
122 Player_2  Session 4245.9002 31/7/18 Main Training
123 Player_1  Session 4868.2153  2/8/18 Main Training
124 Player_2  Session 4515.1996  2/8/18 Main Training
125 Player_2  Session 3215.8634  7/8/18 Main Training
126 Player_2 Modified  551.8737  7/8/18 Main Training
127 Player_2  Session 4264.7384  9/8/18 Main Training
128 Player_1  Session 4038.1687 16/8/18 Main Training
129 Player_2  Session 4751.6978 16/8/18 Main Training
130 Player_1      RTP 4038.1687 16/8/18 Main Training
131 Player_2 Modified  229.6872 16/8/18 Main Training
132 Player_2 Modified  342.2797 16/8/18 Main Training
133 Player_1  Session 3573.4509 23/8/18 Main Training
134 Player_2  Session 3717.3467 23/8/18 Main Training
reprex()
#> Error: <text>:1:16: unexpected symbol
#> 1:       Player   Period
#>                    ^
```
````

I would like to remove rows of the data frame based on multiple criteria using `dplyr`. Specifically, I would like to remove rows containing `Session` where there is `Modified` or `RTP` sharing the same `Date`. For example, as `Player_2` completed `Modified` training on the `7/8/2018`, I would like his `Session` data removed for that date.

````html
```
      Player   Period      Dist   Date          Type
125 Player_2  Session 3215.8634 7/8/18 Main Training
126 Player_2 Modified  551.8737 7/8/18 Main Training
#> Error: <text>:1:16: unexpected symbol
#> 1:       Player   Period
#>                    ^
```
````

Likewise for `16/8/2018` where `Player_1` and `Player_2` completed `Modified` and `RTP` training, respectively, on that day.

````html
```
      Player   Period      Dist    Date          Type
128 Player_1  Session 4038.1687 16/8/18 Main Training
129 Player_2  Session 4751.6978 16/8/18 Main Training
130 Player_1      RTP 4038.1687 16/8/18 Main Training
131 Player_2 Modified  229.6872 16/8/18 Main Training
132 Player_2 Modified  342.2797 16/8/18 Main Training
#> Error: <text>:1:16: unexpected symbol
#> 1:       Player   Period
#>                    ^
```
````

I have filtered data in the past using code such as this.

````html
```
db18 <- db18 %>%
  filter(Period %in% c("Session"))
```
````

However, I wish to remove athlete `Session` data containing `Modified` or `RTP` so as it doesn't 'contaminate' the analysis I am trying to perform. Wondering how I can do this if it's possible.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one approach is to use the `group_by()` function first then you are applying the filter to the groups. In the code below I have used `group_by()` and `mutate()` to create a new column on which to filter. There may be a more elegant solution but this might get you started.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
~Player,   ~Period,      ~Dist,    ~Date,       
'Player_2',  'Session', 4245.9002, '31/7/18',
'Player_1',  'Session', 4868.2153, '2/8/18',
'Player_2',  'Session', 4515.1996,  '2/8/18',
'Player_2',  'Session', 3215.8634,  '7/8/18',
'Player_2', 'Modified',  551.8737,  '7/8/18',
'Player_2',  'Session', 4264.7384,  '9/8/18',
'Player_1',  'Session', 4038.1687, '16/8/18',
'Player_2',  'Session', 4751.6978, '16/8/18',
'Player_1',      'RTP', 4038.1687, '16/8/18',
'Player_2', 'Modified',  229.6872, '16/8/18',
'Player_2', 'Modified',  342.2797, '16/8/18',
'Player_1',  'Session', 3573.4509, '23/8/18',
'Player_2',  'Session', 3717.3467, '23/8/18'
)

df %>%
  group_by(Player, Date) %>%
  mutate(filter_col = ifelse(all(c('Session','Modified') %in% Period), 'delete', 'keep'),
         filter_col = ifelse(all(c('Session','RTP') %in% Period), 'delete', filter_col)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(filter_col == 'keep')
```

Comment: Nice approach, but the OP wanted to delete the row/s of `df$Period == 'Session'` of a player when there are also `df$Period == 'Modified(or)RTP'` rows for a particular date.

Comment: You could also build filter with variations on the length of the group. So `mutate(filter = ifelse(n() > 1 & 'Session' %in% Period, 'Delete', 'Keep'))` would indicates a group has 'Session' and some other value

Comment: Thank you @mrjoh3. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps you.

```
player <- read.csv("player.csv")
player

player
    Id   Player   Period      Dist     Date          Type
1  122 Player_2  Session 4245.9002 31/07/18 Main Training
2  123 Player_1  Session 4868.2153 02/08/18 Main Training
3  124 Player_2  Session 4515.1996 02/08/18 Main Training
4  125 Player_2  Session 3215.8634 07/08/18 Main Training
5  126 Player_2 Modified  551.8737 07/08/18 Main Training
6  127 Player_2  Session 4264.7384 09/08/18 Main Training
7  128 Player_1  Session 4038.1687 16/08/18 Main Training
8  129 Player_2  Session 4751.6978 16/08/18 Main Training
9  130 Player_1      RTP 4038.1687 16/08/18 Main Training
10 131 Player_2 Modified  229.6872 16/08/18 Main Training
11 132 Player_2 Modified  342.2797 16/08/18 Main Training
12 133 Player_1  Session 3573.4509 23/08/18 Main Training
13 134 Player_2  Session 3717.3467 23/08/18 Main Training
```

Grouping by `Player` and `Date` Columns. Then extracting the Id's if a particular `Date` is having
`Modified(or)RTP` along with `Session`.

```
library(dplyr)
removable <- player %>%  group_by_(.dots = c("Player", "Date")) %>% 
  filter( (sum(Period == 'Session') >= 1) & ((sum(Period == 'Modified') != 0) | (sum(Period == 'RTP') != 0 ))) %>%
  filter(Period == 'Session')
```

Now dropping the rows from `player` dataframe if any `player$Id` matches with the `removable$Id`

```
player <- player[!(player$Id  %in% removable$Id), ]
player

    Id   Player   Period      Dist     Date          Type
1  122 Player_2  Session 4245.9002 31/07/18 Main Training
2  123 Player_1  Session 4868.2153 02/08/18 Main Training
3  124 Player_2  Session 4515.1996 02/08/18 Main Training
5  126 Player_2 Modified  551.8737 07/08/18 Main Training
6  127 Player_2  Session 4264.7384 09/08/18 Main Training
9  130 Player_1      RTP 4038.1687 16/08/18 Main Training
10 131 Player_2 Modified  229.6872 16/08/18 Main Training
11 132 Player_2 Modified  342.2797 16/08/18 Main Training
12 133 Player_1  Session 3573.4509 23/08/18 Main Training
13 134 Player_2  Session 3717.3467 23/08/18 Main Training
```

Comment: Thank you @msr_003. This method was also helpful.